# IBM MQ container fails to start on Win2k19 server

Tags: docker, ibm-mq, windows-server-2019

I am trying to setup the IBM MQ container image on an azure windows 2019 server VM. I have enabled `LCOW` and set the `experimental` feature to true. Below are some of the important configurations -

```
    C:\Users\xyz>docker info
        Client:
         Debug Mode: false
         Plugins:
          cluster: Manage Docker clusters (Docker Inc., v1.2.0)

     Server Version: 19.03.5
...
     Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
      Windows:
      LCOW:
     Logging Driver: json-file
     Plugins:
      Volume: local
      Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
      Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
     Swarm: inactive
     Default Isolation: process
     Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
     Operating System: Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.1039)
     OSType: windows
     Architecture: x86_64
    ...
 Debug Mode: false
     Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
     Labels:
     Experimental: true
     Insecure Registries:
      127.0.0.0/8
     Live Restore Enabled: false
```

When i run the image it crashes after a few seconds. The log of the container is as below -

```
    2020-03-17T15:47:10.082Z CPU architecture: amd64
    2020-03-17T15:47:10.083Z Linux kernel version: 4.14.35-linuxkit
    2020-03-17T15:47:10.084Z Base image: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.1 (Ootpa)
    2020-03-17T15:47:10.095Z Running as user ID 0 (root) with primary group 0
    2020-03-17T15:47:10.095Z Capabilities (bounding set): chown,dac_override,fowner,fsetid,kill,setgid,setuid,setpcap,net_bind_service,net_raw,sys_chroot,mknod,audit_write,setfcap
    2020-03-17T15:47:10.095Z seccomp enforcing mode: disabled
    2020-03-17T15:47:10.096Z Process security attributes: none
    2020-03-17T15:47:10.097Z Detected '9p' volume mounted to /mnt/mqm
    2020-03-17T15:47:10.248Z Set password for "admin" user
    2020-03-17T15:47:10.321Z Set password for "app" user
    2020-03-17T15:47:10.369Z Using queue manager name: QM1
    2020-03-17T15:47:11.088Z Created directory structure under /var/mqm
    2020-03-17T15:47:11.089Z Image created: 2019-12-05T18:39:02+00:00
    2020-03-17T15:47:11.089Z Image tag: ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev:9.1.4.0-r1-amd64
    2020-03-17T15:47:11.478Z MQ version: 9.1.4.0
    2020-03-17T15:47:11.478Z MQ level: p914-L191127.DE
    2020-03-17T15:47:11.478Z MQ license: Developer
    2020-03-17T15:47:12.859Z Creating queue manager QM1
    2020-03-17T15:47:12.859Z Starting web server
    **2020-03-17T15:47:13.291Z Error 119 creating queue manager: AMQ7077E: You are not authorized to perform the requested operation.**

    2020-03-17T15:47:13.292Z /usr/bin/crtmqm: exit status 119
```

Can someone help in understanding what additional permissions are needed?

Comment: On a regular Linux machine, you have an 'mqm' group and 'mqm' UserId in the 'mqm' group.  Hence, you sudo to the 'mqm' UserId and then start the queue manager.  So, either sudo to mqm UserId or log in as mqm UserId then start your queue manager.

Comment: Are you trying to use a shared volume for the queue manager? If so then Windows doesn't by default allow Docker to write to the shared volume. This might be why you are not being allowed to create the queue. If you are using a shared volume, try removing the parameter, to allow the image to use a default internal directory.